# Does Star Wars have an official text adventure game?

Tags: star-wars, video-games

I was looking up official Star Trek text adventure games, and was surprised to find [Star Trek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_(1971_video_game)), [Star Trek: The Promethean Prophecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Promethean_Prophecy) and [Star Trek: First Contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_First_Contact_(video_game)).

Do any official Star Wars text adventure games exist? Was there any attempt at producing a Star Wars text adventure while text adventure game were still popular?

Comment: Not sure if you've already heard of it but 1985's Star Trek: The Kobayashi Alternative is another text-based Trek game. It's actually written by one of the best Trek novelists, but is apparently quite buggy

Comment: Web-based game www.swcombine.com

Comment: Mud based game http://www.mudportal.com/play?host=legendsofthejedi.com&port=5656&clean=1&nocenter=1

Comment: I thought you meant like text question adventures. I'd love those. "...You are now stranded on an uncharted paradise planet with Seven Of Nine. What do you do? ..."

Comment: @n00dles - As great as that is, I mean at the height of text adventures, did someone attempt to make a Star Wars text adventure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No official Star Wars text adventure game exists, and I haven't found any mention of an attempt at making one. The few official Star Wars games produced in the 1980s, the heyday of commercial text adventures, were all graphical action games, and LucasArts' first few adventure games (*Labyrinth*, *Maniac Mansion*, *Zak McKracken*) were all graphical adventure games.

The earliest fan attempt I've been able to find was 1979's *Dog Star Adventure*, which is historically relevant as the first text adventure to have its source code published. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_Star_Adventure):

> The game takes place in the Star Wars universe, loosely following the plot of the movie during the action that takes place on the Death Star. Names of the various characters are changed to avoid copyright issues. The player has to gather a number of items to repair their ship, rescue princess Leya, and escape without being detected by the many Roche Soldiers.
>
> [...]
>
> A port to the Commodore PET was made by David Malmberg in 1980, with most of the names returned to their Star Wars versions.

[image]

Comment: The funny thing is, in the image on the cover has a saucer section that looks like the Enterprise. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_Star_Adventure#/media/File:Dog_Star_Adventure_Softside_front_cover.jpg

Comment: That ASCII art, though…

Comment: @QueenSvetlana That’s not the cover of the game packaging, that’s the cover of the issue of SoftSide magazine which published the code. It’s very unlikely the writer of the game had any input into what was on that cover.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I realized that after I looked into a little deeper. I was going to post a question here about why the cover art was for Star Trek, but then I read the text at the bottom of the wiki page that explained it.